# Display random categories

Tags: categories

I'm using the `get_categories` template tag to display a list of categories in a sidebar widget. I would like the widget to display a completely random selection of categories on each page load. I realize I can use the `orderby=>rand` parameter but my understanding is that this only rearranges the order of the fetched categories.

For example, if I have 100 categories and want to display 5 categories I could have the `number` parameter set to `number=>5` and `orderby` to `orderby=>rand` but this would fetch the same 5 categories each time and only rearrange the ordering of those categories. Is that how it works?

I found the following code snippet:

```
$cats ='';
$categories=get_categories();
$rand_keys = array_rand($categories, 5); // 5 is the number of categories you want
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
    $cats .= $categories[$key]->term_id .',';
}
```

Is it necessary to use something like this to get a completely random selection of posts?

Comment: you could assign a number to each category and get a rand number, but it gets tricky, because a random number is something complex, you could get  the same number 7 times in a row and its still considered random =[, i am curios about the solution for this.

Comment: @jrcollins it is not necessary to obtain a random selection of categories in order to retrieve a random selection of posts. So do you want a random selection of posts, or a random selection of categories?

Comment: I want to show a random selection of categories, not posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly [`get_categories()` and `get_terms()` won't likely ever support `'orderby' => 'rand'`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21875) which really leaves you with two options - get every category and select 5 randomly, or construct your own `WP_Query` to query categories with `'orderby' => 'rand'`. The former is easier to implement, and will likely have better performance (unless you have an very large number of categories, perhaps).

So for your purposes, the following would suffice:

```
$categories = get_categories();
shuffle( $categories );
$categories = array_slice( $categories, 0, 5 );
```

After which `$categories` would contain 5 randomly selected categories.

Technically, the `rand_keys()` approach is slightly faster. But in practice the difference is negligible (we're talking nanoseconds), unless you're working with hundreds of thousands of categories.

It's worth noting that if your WordPress installation doesn't contain at least 5 categories the above code will throw an error (as would the snippet in your question), since you cannot take the first 5 elements of an array that's only say 3 elements long.

You could improve upon it by throwing it into a function to make it reusable and more flexible, and adding a couple checks to help avoid potential errors:

```
function get_random_categories( $number, $args = null ) {
  $categories = get_categories( $args ); // Get all the categories, optionally with additional arguments

  // If there aren't enough categories, use as many as possible to avoid an error
  if( $number > count( $categories ) )
    $number = count( $categories );

  // If no categories are available or none were requested, return an empty array
  if( $number === 0 )
    return array();

  shuffle( $categories ); // Mix up the category array randomly

  // Return the first $number categories from the shuffled list
  return array_slice( $categories, 0, $number );
}
```

With that function loaded, you could simply call `$categories = get_random_categories( 5 );` to obtain an array containing 5 random categories - and if the installation has fewer than five categories in total, it would simply return as many as are available, in random order.

Obtaining random posts is much easier, as you can simply use the `'orderby' => 'rand'` argument, as you mentioned - when omitting taxonomy and category arguments, a query will return posts from all categories by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, what exactly is the advantage of this method compared to using the `rand_keys()` approach? Also, could explain the `$number` variable?

Comment: There's really no advantage - it's just easier to write and understand. But no big disadvantage, either. The `$number` argument is just for the sake of making it a more flexible function which can return any desired number of random categories. The two `if()` conditionals just catch things which might cause errors - you can't return the first 5 elements of an array which only has 3 elements in it, for example. In a similar manner, in the snippet in your question, `array_rand()` would throw an error if the WordPress installation it was used in doesn't have 5 categories in the database.

Comment: So for your purposes, you could call `get_random_categories( 5 )` to retrieve an array of 5 random categories. If you were so inclined however, you could take the logic out of the function, remove the `$args` variable, remove the two `if`s, and replace `$number` in the `array_slice()` call with `5` - it should function just as well, so long as you have at least 5 categories in your database.

Comment: I added this info to the answer, hope it clears things up =]

Comment: So, I would need to define `$number` as the number of categories I want to display? For example, `$number=5` if I wanted to display 5 categories?

Comment: In the second form - the function definition - so long as the function is defined before you call it (you place the function definition I wrote in your theme's `functions.php` file or a plugin file, and you use it in a template file) you would simply use `get_random_categories(5)` in order to obtain five random categories. Since `$number` is defined as the first parameter in the function definition, when you call `get_random_cateogories(5)`, the the logic in the function definition will execute, and `$number` will contain the value `5`, since that was the first thing you put in the parenthesis

Comment: If this doesn't make sense, you might want to run through a PHP tutorial such as ([one](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/1)) ([of](https://www.udemy.com/introduction-to-php-programming-training-course/)) ([these](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_introduction.htm)). Or I can try my best to run you through it and answer any questions in 10 or so hours in a StackExchange chat, if you're available

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks for the explanation. I appreciate your help.